# How to hide value next input type = range?

Tags: html, css

Do you have any idea how can I delete value next to slider, I think it's inherited but I checked css and html file and didn't find what can cause it.
[image: slider]

```html
<input type="range">
```

Comment: Is this a custom component? Post the files here, no idea what that is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the reason (<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>)